# Error in my MainApp in my EmployeeStore

Tags: java, hashmap

Hey i made an Edit method to edit the content of the EmployeeStore such as edit the names,id's and e-mails.  So in the menu i have a switch statement.  And in the edit option im setting

```
 System.out.println("Edit");
           Employee employee2 = MenuMethods.userInput();
           Store.searchByName(employee2);
         if (employee != null)
        {
            employee.setEmployeeName("Joe");
            employee.setEmployeeId(1);
            employee.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
           Store.edit(employee);
           Store.print();
```

but the problem is the method searchByName has an error which reads: The method searchByName(String) in the type EmployeeStore is not applicable for the arguments (Employee).  I dont know what is wrong with this and i am using this same steps for the add method in my MainApp.

Here is my code.

MainApp

```
//Imports.
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************  
public class MainApp
{
    //The Scanner is declared here for use throughout the whole MainApp.
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();

    }
    public void start()
    {
//Create a Store named Store and add Employee's to the Store.
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));
//********************************************************************      

/*Test Code.
        Store.searchByName("James O' Carroll");
        Store.print();
        Store.searchByEmail("gmail.com");
        Employee andy = Store.searchByEmail("hotmail.com");
        System.out.println(andy);
        Employee employee = Store.searchByName("James O' Carroll");
        if (employee != null)
        {
            employee.setEmployeeName("Joe");
            employee.setEmployeeId(1);
            employee.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
           Store.edit(employee);
           Store.print();
        }*/
//********************************************************************      

        int choice ;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Company Database.");
        do
        {
         choice = MenuMethods.getMenuChoice(
                "1.\tView All" +
                "\n2.\tAdd" +
                "\n3.\tDelete" +
                "\n4.\tDelete All " +
                "\n5.\tEdit" +
                "\n6.\tSearch" +
                "\n7.\tPrint"+
                "\n8.\tExit", 8, "Please enter your choice:", "Error [1,8] Only");
         //String temp = keyboard.nextLine();  This prevented entering the choice.
        switch (choice) 
        {
            case 1:
                 System.out.println("View All");
                Store.print();

                break;

        case 2:
             System.out.println("Add");
                Employee employee = MenuMethods.userInput();
                Store.add(employee);

                break;

        case 3:
             System.out.println("Delete");
                //Store.delete();


                break;

        case 4:
                System.out.println("Delete All");
                Store.clear();

                break;
        case 5:
           System.out.println("Edit");
           Employee employee2 = MenuMethods.userInput();
           Store.searchByName(employee2);
         if (employee != null)
        {
            employee.setEmployeeName("Joe");
            employee.setEmployeeId(1);
            employee.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
           Store.edit(employee);
           Store.print();

            break;
        case 6:
             System.out.println("Search");
             Employee employee1 = MenuMethods.userInput();
             Store.searchByName(employee1);


            break;
        case 7:
             System.out.println("Print");
            Store.print();

            break;
        case 8:
             System.out.println("Exit");

            break;
        }


        } while (choice != 8);

     }
}
```

Edit method

```
public void edit(Employee employee)
    {
        map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
    }
```

UserInput method

```
public static Employee userInput()
    {
         String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee ID:");
         int employeeId = keyboard.nextInt();
         temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee E-mail address:");
         String employeeEmail  = keyboard.nextLine();
         return e = new Employee(employeeName , employeeId, employeeEmail);

    }
    //********************************************************************
//Method for validating the choice.
         public static int getMenuChoice(String menuString, int limit, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
         {
                System.out.println(menuString);
                int choice = inputAndValidateInt(1, limit, prompt, errorMessage);
                return choice;
         }
    //********************************************************************
    //This method is used in the getMenuChoice method.
            public static int inputAndValidateInt(int min, int max, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
            {
                int number;
                boolean valid;
                do {
                    System.out.print(prompt);
                    number = keyboard.nextInt();
                    valid = number <= max && number >= min;
                    if (!valid) {
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                } while (!valid);
                return number;
            }
    //********************************************************************
```

Comment: [Again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474969/adding-userinput-to-employeestore#comment15151495_11474969), where is the implementation of `MenuMethods.getMenuChoice()`?

Comment: apoligies i keep forgetting to add it in.  I'll edit it now.

Comment: What would you like to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells exactly what's wrong:

> The method searchByName(String) in the type EmployeeStore is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Employee)

Your method `searchByName` takes parameter `String`, while you are passing it an `Employee` object.

There's a few in your code, one of them:

```
 case 5:
           System.out.println("Edit");
           Employee employee2 = MenuMethods.userInput();
           Store.searchByName(employee2);
```

You are passing in `employee2`, which is of type `Employee`

Where's your `searchByName` method implementation?
The method name "`byName`" suggest you want to search by a name `String`, not an `object`. so simple solution would likely to do:

```
Store.searchByName(employee2.getName());
```

On a side note, your code looks horrible to read / bad design.

Comment: Yeah that would work but i need the user to first search for the Employee name they want.

Comment: That sounds like a totally different question, you can open another thread and please put better formatting on your code and only post relevant code chunks. Also present your problem in a clear, concise manner.